# Tasksel error in 14.04 preseed

Tags: 14.04, preseed, tasksel

I have a 14.04 preseed that errors and bails out with this being reported to syslog:

```
Jul 23 17:54:12 pkgsel: starting tasksel
Jul 23 17:54:13 in-target: Unknown option: debconf-apt-from
Jul 23 17:54:13 in-target: Unknown option: debconf-apt-to
Jul 23 17:54:13 in-target: Usage:
Jul 23 17:54:13 in-target: tasksel install <task>...
Jul 23 17:54:13 in-target: tasksel remove <task>...
Jul 23 17:54:13 in-target: tasksel [options]
Jul 23 17:54:13 in-target:  -t, --test          test mode; don't really do anything
Jul 23 17:54:13 in-target:      --new-install   automatically install some tasks
Jul 23 17:54:13 in-target:      --list-tasks    list tasks that would be displayed and exit
Jul 23 17:54:13 in-target:      --task-packages list available packages in a task
Jul 23 17:54:13 in-target:      --task-desc     returns the description of a task
Jul 23 17:54:13 main-menu[220]: WARNING **: Configuring 'pkgsel' failed with error code 1
Jul 23 17:54:13 main-menu[220]: WARNING **: Menu item 'pkgsel' failed.
Jul 23 17:54:16 main-menu[220]: INFO: Modifying debconf priority limit from 'high' to 'medium'
Jul 23 17:54:16 debconf: Setting debconf/priority to medium
Jul 23 17:54:21 main-menu[220]: INFO: Menu item 'save-logs' selected
```

I've been able to reproduce the error on my local machine by doing this:

```
[user@pc:~]
 tasksel --debconf-apt-to  
Unknown option: debconf-apt-to
Usage:
tasksel install <task>...
tasksel remove <task>...
tasksel [options]
-t, --test          test mode; don't really do anything
    --new-install   automatically install some tasks
    --list-tasks    list tasks that would be displayed and exit
    --task-packages list available packages in a task
    --task-desc     returns the description of a task
```

I'm not sure where the preseed is giving this information, since the only time `tasksel` is initiated is right before `pkgsel`, here:

```
tasksel tasksel/first multiselect standard
```

Watching the installer, it gets to `popcon` then gives me that error. The only thing in the preseed that is after the `popcon` option is the boot loader stuff. I'm thoroughly confused and would appreciate any help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you find a solution for this - I have the exact same issue when using a local HTTP source for Ubuntu 12.04.

If I use

```
d-i     mirror/http/hostname select dk.archive.ubuntu.com
```

instead of our own local repository

```
d-i     mirror/http/hostname select srv-wds-nsb1

d-i     mirror/http/directory   string  /LinuxDist/Ubuntu/12.04_x64_LTS
```

everything works just fine.